# Dataframe dictionary printing single quotes

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I have a data frame the headervalue column is dictonary and it gives single quotes but I need double quotes how can I do it ?

```
HeaderID    Headervalue
ID        |{'word': 'link'}
ID        |{'word': 'link'}
ID        |{'word': 'link'}
ID        |{'word': 'link'}
```

I have tried

json.dumps(dictionary)
dictionary.to_json()
string replace

```
list = {}
    for i in data['docs']:
        list[i['word']]= i['link']

    return list
```

I need it something like this

```
HeaderID    Headervalue
ID        |{"word": "link"}
ID        |{"word": "link"}
ID        |{"word": "link"}
ID        |{"word": "link"}
```

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want this? In what situation do the types of quotes shown in the `repr` of a Python dictionary matter? Because as far as Python is concerned, the string `'word'` is the same as the string `"word"`.

Comment: this dataframe is outputted to a csv and consumer of this CSV doesn't want single quotes

Comment: Can you show the code you're using the build the CSV file? Because if you're using a library for it, it may have options for quote characters. The `csv` module for instance, has a `quotechar` argument that you can pass to many methods to specify what character to use for the quotation marks.

Comment: I did try to add quotechar but it adds more quotes somthing like this "{""word": ""link""}"

Comment: Please show the code. We can't troubleshoot your CSV creation code if you don't show it to us.